# How do I create an in-memory class and then include it in Perl?

Tags: perl, require

So I am toying with some black magic in Perl (eventually we all do :-) and I am a little confused as to exactly how I am supposed to be doing all of this.  Here is what I'm starting with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';
my $classname = 'Frew';
my $foo = bless({ foo => 'bar' }, $classname);
no strict;
*{"$classname\::INC"} = sub {
      use strict;
      my $data =  qq[
         package $classname
         warn 'test';
         sub foo {
            print "test?";
         }
      ];
      open my $fh, '<', \$data;
      return $fh;
   };
use strict;
unshift @INC, $foo;
require $foo;
use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper(\@INC);
$classname->foo;
```

I get the following errors (depending on whether my require line is commented out):

With require:

```
Recursive call to Perl_load_module in PerlIO_find_layer at crazy.pl line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

without:

```
$VAR1 = [
      bless( {
               'foo' => 'bar'
             }, 'Frew' ),
      'C:/usr/site/lib',
      'C:/usr/lib',
      '.'
    ];
Can't locate object method "foo" via package "Frew" at crazy.pl line 24.
```

Any wizards who know some of this black magic already: please answer!  I'd love to learn more of this arcana :-)

Also note:  I know that I can do this kind of stuff with Moose and other lighter helper modules, I am mostly trying to learn, so recommendations to use such-and-such a module will not get my votes :-)

***Update***:  Ok, I guess I wasn't quite clear originally with my question.  I basically want to generate a Perl class with a string (that I will manipulate and do interpolation into) based on an external data structure.  I imagine that going from what I have here (once it works) to that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you actually trying to accomplish? To put it another way, _why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @Telemachus: well, the main reason is to learn, but I am also trying to generate some classes based on some JSON.  I'll probably do a writeup about it on my blog once I get it running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a version which works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $class = 'Frew';

{
    no strict 'refs';
    *{ "${class}::INC" } = sub {
        my ($self, $req) = @_;
        return unless $req eq  $class;
        my $data = qq{
            package $class;
            sub foo { print "test!\n" };
            1;
        };
        open my $fh, '<', \$data;
        return $fh;
    };
}

my $foo = bless { }, $class;
unshift @INC, $foo;

require $class;
$class->foo;
```

The `@INC` hook gets the name of the file (or string passed to `require`) as the second argument, and it gets called *every* time there is a `require` or `use`. So you have to check to make sure we're trying to load `$classname` and ignore all other cases, in which case perl continues down along `@INC`. Alternatively, you can put the hook at the end of `@INC`. This was the cause of your recursion errors.

ETA: IMHO, a much better way to achieve this would be to simply build the symbol table dynamically, rather than generating code as a string. For example:

```
no strict 'refs';
*{ "${class}::foo" } = sub { print "test!\n" };
*{ "${class}::new" } = sub { return bless { }, $class };

my $foo = $class->new;
$foo->foo;
```

No `use` or `require` is necessary, nor messing with evil `@INC` hooks.

Comment: The mysterious crash I experienced when I thought I tried the equivalent of your code is gone ... Dunno what caused. Anyway +1 for solving the issue properly as well as stressing that this is very unnecessary for the purpose stated by the OP. I am going to delete my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I do this:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

my $class = class {
    has 'foo' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1);
    method bar() {
        say "Hello, world; foo is ", $self->foo;
    }
};
```

Then you can use $class like any other metaclass:

```
my $instance = $class->name->new( foo => 'foo bar' );
$instance->foo; # foo-bar
$instance->bar; # Hello, world; foo is foo-bar
```

etc.

If you want to dynamically generate classes at runtime, you need to create the proper metaclass, instantiate it, and then use the metaclass instance to generate instances.  Basic OO. Class::MOP handles all the details for you:

```
my $class = Class::MOP::Class->create_anon_class;
$class->add_method( foo => sub { say "Hello from foo" } );
my $instance = $class->new_object;
...
```

If you want to do it yourself so that you can waste your time debugging something, perhaps try:

```
sub generate_class_name {
    state $i = 0;
    return '__ANON__::'. $i++;
}

my $classname = generate_class_name();
eval qq{
    package $classname;
    sub new { my \$class = shift; bless {} => \$class }
    ...
};

my $instance = $classname->new;
```

Comment: I like this answer the most, but I *did* ask for no Moose :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple example of how to do this, [read the source of Class::Struct](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/NWCLARK/perl-5.8.9/lib/Class/Struct.pm).

However, if I needed the ability to dynamically build classes for some production code, I'd look at MooseX::Declare, as suggested by jrockway.

Answer (score -3):

A Perl class is little more than a data structure (usually a hashref)
that has been blessed into a package in which one or more class
methods are defined.

It is certainly possible to define multiple package namespaces in one
file; I don't see why this wouldn't be possible in an `eval` construct
that is compiled at run-time (see `perlfunc` for the two different
`eval` forms).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

eval q[
    package Foo;
    sub new {
        my ( $class, %args ) = @_;
        my $self = bless { %args }, $class;
        return $self;
    }
    1;
];
die $@ if $@;

my $foo = Foo->new(bar => 1, baz => 2) or die;

say Dumper $foo;
```

Comment: Perl doesn't really have classes (just namespaces), and you've confused that with instances.

Comment: Oh well. Let's just replace 'little' with 'nothing' then.